# Outlook VBA Recipient email

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to pick up the recipient email address and insert into the SQL database but im getting a runtime error 424 object required,

The following is highlighted in yellow "Set recips = Mail.Recipients"

I don't know what i have done wrong any help would be appreciated

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim Atmt As attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim strPrompt As String
Dim vError As Variant
Dim sErrors As String

i = 0

For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
Debug.Print Atmt.FileName

If (UCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 4)) = UCase("docx")) Or _
   (UCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 3)) = UCase("pdf")) Or _
   (UCase(Right(Atmt.FileName, 3)) = UCase("doc")) Then

i = i + 1

End If


Next Atmt

    If i > 0 Then

    strPrompt = "You have attached a document. Is this a CV Submission?"

        If MsgBox(strPrompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check for Attachment") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = False

        Else:

              Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
              Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
              Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
              Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
              Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
              Dim sConnString As String


              ' Create the connection string.
              sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=WIN-NBST3PHVFV4\ECLIPSE;" & _
                            "Initial Catalog=OBlive;" & _
                            "User ID=outlook;Password=0Zzy007;"

              ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
             Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
             Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
             Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
             Set recips = Mail.Recipients

             ' Open the connection and execute.
             conn.Open sConnString
             Set rs = conn.Execute("INSERT INTO dbo.Submissions (CV_Sent, Consultant, Timestamp, Recipient) VALUES ( '1','" & myNamespace.CurrentUser & "', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '" & recip.Address & "' )")
             ' Clean up
             If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
             Set conn = Nothing
             Set rs = Nothing

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see where have you declared/initialized `Mail` object. Should it be `Set recips = Item.Recipients`?

Answer (score 0):

1. 'Mail' occurs only one in your Sub. Is it a global (pfui) variable? Are you sure it's properly initialized before you call `Application_ItemSend`? [**added**: The code snippet you linked to in your comment recieves an Outlook.MailItem named `mail` as parameter; that makes @simoco's advice to try `Set recips = Item.Recipients` (Item beeing your parameter name) promising; of course it will only work if your calling code initilized that argument properly.]
2. You Dim and use `recip`, but I don't see where you assign a value to it.

Comment: Im not sure if it is properly initialized. i'm attemtpting to re-use the code from [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868695(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: Well thats really helpful isnt it!